# Как вывести конечный результат цикла в python?

Tags: python

Как вывести конечный результат цикла в python?
Есть функция которая считает гласные в слове

```
def get_count(sentence):
    i = 0
    for index in range(len(sentence)):
        if sentence[index] == "a" or sentence[index] == "e" or sentence[index] == "e" or sentence[index] == "i" or sentence[index] == "o" or sentence[index] == "u":
            i = i + 1
            print(i)
        else:
            print("Not a vowel")

get_count("aeib")
```

И при замене print(i) на return i выводится просто 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_count(sentence):
    i = 0
    for index in range(len(sentence)):
        if sentence[index] in {"a", "e", "i", "u", "o"}:
            i += 1
    return i

print(get_count("aeib"))
```

А поскольку индексы вам не нужны, n1tr0xs подсказывает использовать более простой цикл:

```
def get_count(sentence):
    i = 0
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in {"a", "e", "i", "u", "o"}:
            i += 1
    return i
```

Comment: почему бы тогда не использовать `for letter in sentence`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только количество гласных букв, то можно так

```
def get_count(sentence):
    return len(list(filter(lambda char: char in "aeiuo", sentence)))

print(get_count("aeib"))
```

В Вашем случае выводится единица потому что `return` сразу завершает выполнение функции, т.е. в Вашем случае при нахождении первой гласной буквы. Чтобы Ваш код работал правильно, нужно `return i` поместить после цикла

Comment: а генератор списков на 6 символов короче :)  `return len([char for char in sentence if char in "aeiuo"])`

Comment: @AlexTitov всю картину портит то, что `filter` нужно оборачивать в список, без этого было бы красивее.

Answer (score 0):

Ну и до кучи совсем уж "однострочник" в "функциональном стиле" )

```py
def get_count(sentence):
    return sum(map({"a", "e", "i", "u", "o"}.__contains__, sentence))

print(get_count("aeib"))
```